# Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two random numbers independently drawn from a set of numbers with replacement

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two random numbers independently drawn from a set of numbers with replacement. Write a formula for $E[(X_1 - X_2)^2]$

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this. Any hints/explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_{1}-X_{2}\right)^{2}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}^{2} - 2 X_{1}X_{2} + X_{2}^{2}\right] =
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}^{2}\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[X_{2}^{2}\right] -\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}X_{2}\right]$$
If they are independent and drawn from the same set then
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_{1}-X_{2}\right)^{2}\right] = 2\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}^{2}\right] - 2\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]^{2} = 2 \left(\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}^{2}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]^{2}\right) = 2 Var(X_{1})
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $(X_1-X_2)^2=X_1^2-2X_1X_2+X_2^2$. Hence our expression is equivalent to
$$\mathbb{E}(X_1^2-2X_1X_2+X_2^2)$$
By linearity of expectation, this is equivalent to
$$\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)+\mathbb{E}(X_2^2)-2\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)$$
Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, this is equivalent to
$$\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)+\mathbb{E}(X_2^2)-2\mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(X_2)$$